# Get Azure deviceProvisioning Service EnrollmentGroupKeys programatically C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-dps

This should work, but my strings are null

```
/Get the details for this group
    EnrollmentGroup group = await provisioningClient.GetEnrollmentGroupAsync(groupId);
    logger.LogInformation("Got Enrollment Group: {group}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group));
    var attestation  =(SymmetricKeyAttestation)group.Attestation;
    var primaryKey = attestation.PrimaryKey;
    var secondaryKey = attestation.SecondaryKey;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryKey))
        logger.LogWarning("No Primary Key");
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondaryKey))
        logger.LogWarning("No Secondary Key");    

    logger.LogInformation("Got Keys {pri} and {sec}", primaryKey, secondaryKey);
```

[GetEnrollmentGroupAsync(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.provisioningserviceclient.getenrollmentgroupasync?view=azure-dotnet) seems to work.
It returns an enrollmeent group that has a symmetric key attestation.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.symmetrickeyattestation?view=azure-dotnet), there is a getter for those.

Comment: the primary and secondary keys are only showing while creating the enrollment group and not  while getting the  enrollment    [groups](https://i.imgur.com/lNCNJU7.png) details

Answer (score 0):

The correct Call is [GetEnrollmentGroupAttestationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.provisioningserviceclient.getenrollmentgroupattestationasync?view=azure-dotnet)

```
var attestationMechanism = await provisioningClient.GetEnrollmentGroupAttestationAsync(groupId);
    var attestation = (SymmetricKeyAttestation)attestationMechanism.GetAttestation();
    string  primaryKey = attestation.PrimaryKey;
    string secondaryKey = attestation.SecondaryKey;
```

This assumes it was a SymmetricKeyAttestation. [AttestationMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.attestationmechanism?view=azure-dotnet) has a `Type` property if you need to determine type dynamically.